# Subscript out of range Copying Between sheets, vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question bank on one sheet and I have to select 10 questions at random and  generate a question paper with no questions repeating. I am getting a subscript out of range error. Below is the code: error is in line highlited in BOLD

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i, RowNum
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").ClearContents
For i = 1 To 10
generate:
RowNum = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 10, 0)
Cells(i, 3).Value = RowNum
**If Application.CountIf(Sheets(“Sheet1”).[A:A], 
Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(RowNum, “A”)) = 0 Then**
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = 
Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(RowNum, “A”).Value
Else
GoTo generate
End If
Next i
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
Range(“A1”).Value = "Heading"
Range(“A1”).Font.Bold = True
Range(“A1”).Columns.AutoFit
Range(“B1”).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What was wrong with `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")`?

Comment: `GoTo generate`, not really many good use cases for this in 2019, 51 years after the classic [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) was written.

Comment: Well, I disagree. Ever seen the spaghetti code consisting of numerous *if-then-else* or even worse *if-then-else-elseif-else*. A clear GOTO is much more readable than the aforementioned mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you are using an invalid double quote. From your code it is evident that you are using both

```
Range(“A1”).Value = "Heading"
```

Change `“` and `”` to `"` and your code will work else you will get the Subscript out of Range Error.

To reproduce the error you can try this in the immediate window

```
?Sheets(“Sheet1”).Name '<~~ This will give you the error.
?Sheets("Sheet1").Name
```

Comment: hey thanks so much, din realise how the quotes changed, I copied the code from a website.